# catch in exception handling doesn't stop program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

I have this function in a c++ class which I have wrote in visual studio:

```
int info::connectSession()
{
    std::string _ErrMsg;
    std::string _ErrScope;
    int _RetVal = 0;
    MyException errMsg;
    int port = 22;
    try
    {
        if (my_ssh_session == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Error creating ssh session" << std::endl;
            throw errMsg;
            return 0;
        }

        ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, (const void*)(authentication.ip));
        ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, (const void*)(authentication.userName));
        ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
        int rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
        if (rc != SSH_OK) {
            std::cout << "Error with connecting" << std::endl;
            
            _ErrMsg = ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);

            ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
            _RetVal = -1;

            _ErrScope = "Connecting";
            
            //throw std::runtime_error("Error with :" + _ErrScope + _ErrMsg.c_str());
            throw errMsg;
        }

        rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, NULL, (const char*)(authentication.pw));
        if (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS) {
            std::cout << "Authentication failed " << ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session) << std::endl;

            _ErrMsg = ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);

            ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
            ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
            _RetVal = -2;

            _ErrScope = "Authentication";
            //throw std::runtime_error("Error with :" + _ErrScope + _ErrMsg.c_str());
            throw errMsg;

        }

    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cout << "catcher";
        std::cout<< e.what();
        
    }

    return _RetVal;
    
}
```

I call this `connectionState` function from a function in another class( I have these two classes in a single shared library):

```
const int smc_getCoreNumbers(Authorization *autho)
{
    info *inf = new info(autho);
    std::string corenum = inf->coreNumbers();
    int num = std::stoi(corenum.c_str());
    free(inf);
    return num;
}
```

I have written a test program to load my library( which contains those two classes I mentioned), and I pass autho structure in it:

```
struct Authorization
{
    char* ip;
    char* pw;
    char* userName;
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *lib_handle;
    struct Authorization au;
    const int (*fn)(struct Authorization*);   
    au.ip = "my ip";
    au.pw = "my pw";
    au.userName = "my user";
    const char *error;
    lib_handle = dlopen("/path/to/shared/library", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!lib_handle)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    fn = dlsym(lib_handle, "smc_getCoreNumbers");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(1);
    }
 
    int maxspeed;
    maxspeed = (*fn)(&au);
    printf("Valx=%d\n",maxspeed);
    dlclose(lib_handle);
    return 0;
}
```

and MyException class:

```
class MyException : public exception
{
    const char* what() const throw () {
        return "C++ Exception";
    }
};
```

I have used exception handling to throw something when `pw` or `user` or `ip` are wrong. but my program doesn't stop on catch scope when I send wrong information to it and continues to debug until crashes in another function. am I doing something wrong while using exception handling?

Comment: Passing a pointer you got from `new` to `free` has undefined behaviour. Use `delete`.

Comment: What's the definition of `MyException`?

Comment: All your exception handler does is to print a couple of messages. Why are you expecting it to stop the program?

Comment: so what should I do to stop it?use `exit`?and any way it doesn't even  print the messages that I used `cout` to print in it. @molbdnilo

Comment: So assuming `exception` is `std::exception` then you should hit your catch block. Are you saying that you don't, or are you saying that the program doesn't terminate? As molbdnilo says, just because you throw an exception doesn't automatically mean the program terminates.

Comment: @fa7eme That's probably just buffering. Output doesn't have to appear immediately. Flush the output stream if you want to see output immediately.

Comment: Use a debugger. Put breakpoints on your throw statement and inside your catch block.

Comment: @john so there isn't anything wrong with my way of using try catch? should I use `exit` or `terminate` to stop program?

Comment: I have used it. it goes inside catch block and then exits the function and continues until crashes in another function.@n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: There is little point in throwing an exception and catching it in the same function. (It's most popular as a way of pretending that you're avoiding `goto`.) The flow of printing a message and immediately returning  an error code is much easier to follow.

Comment: @fa7eme There nothing illegal about it, but if you want to stop the program then just call `exit` immediately. Seems your misunderstanding was that after catching an exception the program terminates automatically. That's not true. Catching exceptions is normally used when you want to recover from an error, or when you want to report an error that could occur anywhere in your code.

Comment: yes I thought it should exit automatically.thanks a lot. @john

Comment: No, I used g++ for making my library. @LorinczyZsigmond

Comment: Perhaps you accidentally compiled/linked your _main program_ with `cc` instead of `c++`?