# unhandled exception when thowing exception from a function to another function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

I have these class that I had mentioned in this question : [catch in exception handling doesn't stop program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370337/catch-in-exception-handling-doesnt-stop-program) 
 and these is the `coreNumbers` functions that I had in there :

```
std::string info::coreNumbers()
{
    int retValue;
    std::string cpuSpeed = "";
    getSSHState();
    try {
        num = exec_ssh_command(my_ssh_session, "ca /pro/cpuinfo | grep processor");
    }
    catch (MyException &err)
    {
        //exit(0);
         throw err;
    }
    return num;
}
```

I have written "ca" in command on purpose. to get error and exception thrown. and these is my `exec_ssh_command` function :

```
std::string info::exec_ssh_command(ssh_session session, char *command) {
    std::string receive = "";
    int rc, nbytes;
    char buffer[2000];
    MyException errMsg;
    try {
        ssh_channel channel = ssh_channel_new(session);
        if (channel == NULL)
        {
            receive = "Channel allocation failed.";
            errMsg  = MyException(receive);
            throw errMsg;
        }
        rc = ssh_channel_open_session(channel);
        if (rc != SSH_OK) 
        {
            ssh_channel_free(channel);
            receive = "Opening session channel failed.";
            errMsg = MyException(receive);
            throw errMsg;
        }

        rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, command);
        if (rc != SSH_OK) {
            receive = "Channel's request executing failed.";
            errMsg = MyException(receive);
            ssh_channel_close(channel);
            ssh_channel_free(channel);
            throw errMsg;
        }
        nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        receive = buffer;
        if (nbytes > 0)
        {
            receive.erase(nbytes - 1, 2000);
        }
        else
        {
            receive = "Error in command: not found or wrong syntax";
            errMsg = MyException(receive);
            throw errMsg;
        }
        while (nbytes > 0)
        {
            nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        }

        if (nbytes < 0)
        {
            receive = "Error in reading data from channel. ";
            errMsg =  MyException(receive);
            throw errMsg;
        }
        ssh_channel_send_eof(channel);
        ssh_channel_close(channel);
        ssh_channel_free(channel);
        
    }
    catch (MyException &err)
    {
       // std::cerr << err.what()<<flush;
        throw err;
    }
    return receive;
    
}
```

when I run my code, I got `unhandled exception` in the `throw` that I have in `coreNumbers` function. after the exception in `exec_ssh_command` is thrown. am I misunderstood and using something wrong here?

Comment: It looks like `coreNumbers` is catching the exception and then immediately throwing it again. I'm not sure what else that could cause but an unhandled exception.

Comment: Why aren't you doing e.g. `throw MyException("Error in command: not found or wrong syntax");`? You don't need the `errMsg` variable or store a temporary string in `receive`. And why do you `catch` the exception in the `exec_ssh_command` function itself?

Comment: emmm because I wanted to check if anything like commands are wrong or anything wrong with connecting to channel or... is there anything wrong about that? I did throw as you said but it is still same. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: In the `catch` clause in the `coreNumbers` function you have `throw err;`. Who catches that thrown exception? What is the actual problem that's supposed to solve? What is supposed to happen when the `coreNumbers` function catches an exception?

Comment: I want to notify anyone who uses my class to know if anything happened for example in `exec_ssh_command` function. I mean I want to catch exception thrown in there and again throw to upper layer. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Why catch it in `coreNumbers` to begin with? Just let the exception from `exec_ssh_command` continue up the call-stack until it can be properly handled.

Comment: cause I have another programs like `coreNumbers` and in each of them I use that `exec_ssh_command` function. I want to the one who uses these code know that exception happened in which function. is there any better way to do that? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: you always throwing your exception again. Most outer cactth you should not throw it again.

Comment: so in which way I can get this functionality and also not to always throw exception? @IS

Comment: How about a `try catch` around the call to `coreNumbers` (and the "other" functions you call)?

Comment: And as a general design tip: Don't try to use a single exception type to handle multiple different errors. Instead use one exception type for each error. And in general it doesn't matter *where* the exceptions are thrown, usually it's the exception *kind* (its type) that is important. If you want to catch a larger group of different exception types, use inheritance (preferably from the standard exception types).

Comment: In catch you throwing again  throw err;  Just dont do  this when you dont want to throw again.

Comment: now I got `exception unhandled` in the catch that I have in `exece_ssh_command`. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: thanks. it somehow solved my problem and I can print exception error. only there is something that it crashes after the last throw. isn't that a problem? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: If you continue to rethrow the exception, you will get an "unhandled exception". After the exception have been handled, you need to decide what to do: Exit the program? Rethrow the exception (which leads to a "crash")? Or have it been handled in a way that allows your program to continue (in which case you should ***not*** rethrow the exception)?